# When to create a template?

Tags: meteor

For example I have a list, which has header, body, footer, and body has items

so I create something like this

```
<template name="List">
 {{> ListHeader}}
 {{> ListBody data}}
 {{> ListFooter}}
</template>
<template name="ListBody">
 <div class="list-body">
   {{#each items}}
   {{> ListItem data}}
   {{/each}}
 </div>
</template>
```

in ListItem, I will display play some action buttons, like edit/delete according to some init data.

so it will become very complicated. Means, I have to define it when I create `List`:

```
{{> List showEdit=true showDelete=true}}
```

Then in `Template.List.helpers`, define `showEdit` again and pass it to `ListBody`

```
Template.List.helpers({
  showEdit: return this.showEdit:
})

{{> ListBody showEdit=showEdit showDelete=true}}
```

Again define showEdit in ListBody and pass it to ListItem

```
Template.ListBody.helpers({
  showEdit: return this.showEdit:
})

{{> ListItem showEdit=showEdit showDelete=true}}
```

So I think I'm doing something wrong. Maybe I should not create so many templates?
just put them in one place?

When should I create a template? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already shown you understand, separate templates can have a different data contexts which can be confusing / messy. However in many cases this is desirable and can make your code easier to maintain and more readable.

As in your example:

```
{{#each items}}
  {{> listItem}}
{{/each}}
```

In this case the data context passed to `listItem` is automatically set for each item in the array. (Note. you don't need to pass `data` to do this.) So using a new template makes sense here.

Another reason to use a separate template is reusability. As projects grow this become more important and it helps a lot to try and think ahead to what elements you might reuse elsewhere.

As you've shown, you can pass data into a template when you call it. This is neither good nor bad but I would be cautious about doing it too much as this could lead to over-complicated things. In general, you want clean, modular templates that make sense when you look at them and don't leave you hunting around trying to work out why they aren't doing what you expect!

To this end, have a look at [Template level subscriptions](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe) and at [Reactive variables](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg). Together, these can turn templates into powerful modular components. I speak from experience when I say you will thank yourself for getting into the habit of building your templates this way later on.

Finally, the best way to figure this out is to play around a bit and browse through other projects and see what they've done. A word of warning: best practices around template structure has changed as Meteor as grown so some advice online might not take advantage of newer, better ways of doing things.

Answer (score -1):

This is just personal preference. I don't think there's an issue creating as many templates as you are. Why do you write that you think you're doing something wrong?